# Linq query to get Child's Child records

Tags: linq

In my Parent Child scenario, I need to get the custom list of all the customers with their total number of orders and orderitems.

A Customer can have many orders and orders can have many OrderItems. I need to write a query which returns me the collection of entity Objects which has the Customer Entity and Total Orders and Total OrderItems for that Customer object e.g

```
var result = from c in  ctx.Customers
         from o in  ctx.Orders
         from d in  ctx.OrderItems
         select new List<CustomerVM()
         {
            customer = c,
            totalOrders = o.Count,
            totalOrderItems = XXXX  
         }  
public class CustomerVM {
 public Customer customer {get; set;}
 public int totalOrders {get; set;}
public int totalOrderItems {get; set;}
}
```

How can I do that ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SelectMany`:

```
var result = (from c in ctx.Customers
              select new CustomerVM
              {
                  customer = c,
                  totalOrders = c.Orders.Count(),
                  totalOrderItems = c.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems).Count()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I'm getting the following error
Cannot Convert method group 'Count' to  non-delegate type 'int' on 
c.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems).Count

Comment: Sorry, just use parenthesis: `Count()` instead of `Count`

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm running this in SL4 but its not returning any results. When i debug it I got the null value as result although there are 4 Customers with some orders as well.
Any idea why is that? ctx is the DomainContext

Comment: Do you get 4 results if you just query for Customers? `var result = ctx.Customers.ToList();`?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Its Count = 0 but Capacity = 4

Comment: But if I do this then it works
 _customers = new PagedCollectionView(ctx.Customers);
 LoadCustomers();
 public void LoadCustomers()
  { var qry = ctx.GetCustomersQuery();
    LoadOperation loadOp = ctx.Load(qry);
  }

Comment: What's in the `GetCustomersQuery()` method?

Comment: Is it something related to Load Operation that I need to use? because I'm not using that anywhere so its not returning anything. Please note that this is on Silverlight's client side code not the DomainService of Web/Server side.
I did try to use the query in DomainService class but it was giving the error upon the custom object CustomerVM class NOT having the key attribute.

Comment: return this.ObjectContext.Customers;

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `this.ObjectContext.Customers.Select(c => new CustomerVM { customer = c, totalOrders = c.Orders.Count(), totalOrderItems = c.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems).Count() })`?

Comment: I did try that before but as I said earlier that it does not approve the CustomerVM class and give the error that the 'entity CustomerVM in DomainService does not have a key defined.

Comment: I got this working but the customer object is not populating within the retruned list. I'm only able to access the totalOrders and totalOrderItems.

Comment: You can try to project the `Customer` object field by field unless you find a better solution: `.Select(c => new CustomerVM { customer = new Customer { Name = c.Name, ... }, totalOrders = c.Orders.Count() ... })`

Comment: I don't think that this is in select statement. if I look into the MetaData file, there is no property against the public Customer mainCustomer{get;set;} where as for all other there is equivalent one there. Is it because its EF defined entity and cannot be used here?
I need to define the custom class as well to clone this

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly you are doing, but alternatively you can define the customer properties you need directly in the viewmodel: `public class CustomerVM { public string CustomerName {get; set;} ... public int totalOrders {get; set;} public int totalOrderItems {get; set;} }`, and then project onto it in a similar way: `.Select(c => new CustomerVM { customerName = c.Name, ... , totalOrders = c.Orders.Count() ... })`.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm thinking too. Actually I was trying to avoid that just because I don't want to duplicate all the Customer table. BUT i think that's the only way forward. 
Thanks again